# bash run command without exiting on error and tell me its exit code

Tags: bash, shell

From a bash script I want to run a command which might fail, store its exit code in a variable, and run a subsequent command regardless of that exit code.

Examples of what I'm trying to avoid:

Using `set`:

```
set +e  # disable exit on error (it was explicitly enabled earlier)
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME npm test
test_exit_code=$?  # remember exit code of previous command
set -e  # enable exit on error
echo "copying unit test result file to host"
docker cp $CONTAINER_NAME:/home/test/test-results.xml .
exit $test_exit_code
```

Using `if`:

```
if docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME npm test ; then
    test_exit_code=$?
else
    test_exit_code=$?
fi
echo "copying unit test result file to host"
docker cp $CONTAINER_NAME:/home/test/test-results.xml .
exit $test_exit_code
```

Is there a semantically straightforward way to tell bash "run command without exiting on error, and tell me its exit code"?

The best alternative I have is still confusing and requires comments to explain to subsequent developers (it's just a terser if/else):

```
docker exec $CONTAINER_NAME npm test && test_exit_code=$? || test_exit_code=$?
echo "copying unit test result file to host"
docker cp $CONTAINER_NAME:/home/test/test-results.xml .
exit $test_exit_code
```

Comment: Do you need a kind try catch?

Comment: `bash` doesn't normally exit on failure, so you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: You have to use `set -e` to make it exit on failure, but it's not the default.

Comment: `set -e` was explicitly set prior to reaching this point

Comment: Side note: if your code involves POSIX or Bash scripts, I'd recommend to always run the [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net/) linter on the scripts before using them in production: in particular, it would have spotted the missing double quotes around the shell variable `"$CONTAINER_NAME"` (but admittedly, this variable would certainly contain no space nor `*` here, so this specific parameter expansion would have caused no harm here :)

Answer (score 8):

I believe you could just use the `||` operator? Which is equivalent to an "if − else" command.

Would the following address your use case? (otherwise feel free to comment!)

```sh
set -e  # implied in a CI context
exit_status=0
docker exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" npm test || exit_status=$?
docker cp "$CONTAINER_NAME:/home/test/test-results.xml" .
exit "$exit_status"
```

or more briefly:

```sh
set -e  # implied in a CI context
docker exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" npm test || exit_status=$?
docker cp "$CONTAINER_NAME:/home/test/test-results.xml" .
exit "${exit_status:-0}"
```

As an aside, if you are not interested in this exit status code, you can also do something like this:

```sh
set -e  # implied in a CI context
docker exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" npm test || :
docker cp "$CONTAINER_NAME:/home/test/test-results.xml" .
```

For more details on the `|| :` tip, see e.g. this answer on Unix-&-Linux SE:
[Which is more idiomatic in a bash script: `|| true` or `|| :`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78411/297058)

Comment: these are clearer variations of the `or` method

Answer (score 1):

Very simply save the return-code if command failed:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Implied by CI
set -e

# Initialise exit return code
rc=0

# Run command or save its error return code if it fail
docker exec "$CONTAINER_NAME" npm test || rc="$?"

printf '%s\n' "copying unit test result file to host"

# Run other command regardless if first one failed
docker cp "$CONTAINER_NAME:/home/test/test-results.xml" .

# Exit with the return code of the first command
exit "$rc"
```

Comment: Hi Léa! Thanks for your answer, but I believe it is equivalent to mine? but nevermind, you had probably started typing yours while mine was posted ;-)

Comment: Oups yes @ErikMD indeed.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a kind of try catch, to get the exit code and use a simple switch case to run another commands depending on the  error exit code:

```
(
exit 2
#here your command which might fail
)
exit_code=$?

case "$exit_code" in

0)  echo "Success execution"
    #do something
    ;;
1)  echo "Error type 1"
    #do something
    ;;
2)  echo "Error type 2"
    #do something
    ;;
*) echo "Unknown error type: $exit_code"
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: Enclosing the command in parentheses doesn't prevent bash from exiting on error (we did `set -e` at the beginning of the script).

Comment: mmm I used this approach. And it catches. Also I tried this snippet before post it. `set -e` is not required.